# How to make an audio sharing or streaming site like sportify and SoundCloud with django

Tags: html, django, audio, django-models, soundcloud

> I am working on making an audio streaming or sharing site like
>   [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com) and [sportify](http://sportify.com) using django where users can login create account upload audio files share the audio files ...

My question is how do I handle the audio files ...

- do I host the audio files in a separate server
- or use one of those cloud server... If this would like to know which server
- any other think I need to know to go about this project

Thank you

Comment: Such questions are off-topic.
Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Q) do I host the audio files in a separate server
- A) I think it depends on the size of the server. If it's big enough for spotify, it should have multiple server for many audio files.
- Q) or use one of those cloud server... If this would like to know which server
- A) You can use cloud server, but I guess it's more expensive. If the expense is high, you can use cloud server: it's much convenient way.

Do you want to use DRF for this project? I don't know why you want to make streaming site with django. I love django but I think it's not that profit to your purpose.

Comment: So what's the best way to go about it

Comment: well, I think you should build api. Then you can use django-rest-framework, and make front-end browser player with other front framework. (Maybe soundcloud use react) I guess spotify and soundcloud use their own api.